# I am getting an output message when opening .net 4.0 solution file in VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010 sp1

When I am opening .NET 4.0 application in VS 2010, I am getting an Output message as

**Loading F:\Projects..\Project.csproj ...
F:\Projects..\Project.csproj : error  : The project file 'F:\Projects..\Project.csproj' cannot be opened.
The project type is not supported by this installation.**

But I am able to open other projects in the application. They are loaded properly.

Provide me a solution for how to open. Thanks.

Comment: It could be e.g. a Sharepoint project if you don't have Sharepoint installed, or a project created by some other VS plugin where you don't have that plugin installed. Can't you talk to the person who wrote the project?

Comment: mvc 4 architecture used. Presentation Layer alone is not loaded. Remaining all layers loaded without any issue.

Comment: Is MVC4 installed on the machine that the project is failing to load on?

Comment: I have seen this when opening projects within "Visual Studio 2010 Shell" - which has no loaded templates and can open no projects, so a simple class library csproj file cannot be opened with that exact message. Perhaps your project was created with VS2010 Ultimate and you're trying to open in Professional, which is missing some features. It's likely to be something along those lines, or, a corrupt install. Attempt a repair and retry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its one of these two:

1. Your Visual Studio Installation is corrupted (not likely).
2. The Project was created with a verion of Visual studio that supported more project types and your installation supports less. For example if you create a Sharepoint or a Test Manager Project with Visual Studio Ultimate and you try to open it with Visual Studio Proffesional. (most likely).

Another example would be when you create a Web Project using VS Web Express, and after that you try and open it with VS Express for Windows Phone.

Comment: then on the place that it was created additional components and or updates existed whereas in your installation that opens the file, they do not exist.

Comment: Previously I had worked in 2012 which has default mvc4 template. But for 2010, now I had installed Asp.net MVC4 and it solves the issue. Thanks for all.